# Sorting strings from file to new file

Tags: c++

This is my function to get lines from file to strings

```
void getStringsFromFile() {
    ifstream database;
    database.open("Database.txt", ios::app | ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!database) {
        cout << "Kunne ikke indlaese filen..." << endl;
    }
    int count = 0, c = 0;
    string getString, tmp, str[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        while (getline(database, getString)) {
            str[i] = getString;
            cout << "String: [" << count++ << "] " << str[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    sortStrings(getString);
}
```

This is how I'm saving my data to .txt file

```
     if (database.is_open()) {
         database << list[i].navn << "\t" << list[i].addresse << "\t" << list[i].alder << "\t" << list[i].tlf << "\t" << "\n";
         database.close();
```

It outputs like this: line 0 is empty

```
Kasper Jensen   
Jomfrugade 5    21  44556677

Victor Hansen   
Østergade 94    25  54644773
```

I have this function to sort the strings, ascending by insertion. It don't work with string to char

```
void sortStrings(string &lines) {
    string* lines = nullptr;
    string temp;
    int count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (lines[j] > lines[j + 1]) {
                temp = lines[j];
                lines[j] = lines[j + 1];
                lines[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want my code to grab relevant lines from one .txt file and sort it to another. I dont really care which sorting method

I have problems with it recognizing the right strings and grabbing them and outputting them into new file

Comment: `ios::app` (for "append") with an input file makes no sense, you don't need to specify `ios::in` on an input stream, and opening a text file in binary mode is usually not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getStringsFromFile` function will read all lines from the file, and put them all into `str[0]`. Then the `sortStrings` function will attempt to sort a single string. There are other things that looks weird as well.

What I recommend you to do, is to create a [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of strings, read lines in a loop (the `while (getline(...))` loop) and add to the vector, then use the standard [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function to sort the vector.

Once that's done you can write the strings in the vector to a new file.

---

Note that the above assume that there's no specific format in the file, that each line is its separate record. If your file have a specific multi-line record format then that won't work.

If this is the case then I recommend you create a class for the records, implement a stream extract operator for the class (`operator>>` for `std::istream`), and use a loop (`while (file >> my_record_object)`) to read all records into a vector.

Then again sort the vector using `std::sort`, using a suitable ordering function (lambda or overloaded `operator<` function for the class). Then write the data in the vector to the new file using an overloaded `operator<<` function.

Comment: `void getStringsFromFile() {
    ifstream database;
    database.open("Database.txt", ios::app | ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!database) {
        cout << "Kunne ikke indlaese filen..." << endl;
    }
    string line;
    vector<string> mylines;
    while (getline(database, line)) {
        mylines.push_back(line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    sort(line.begin(), line.end());
}`

I've made this now, how does I access every line on its own?

Comment: @VIGGO420 Something like that's what I'm talking about in the first section. But you need to sort the *vector*, not `line` which is a single line from the file (the last one to be more specific). Once you fix that, it reads and sorts the lines without any consideration about the contents of the file.

Comment: @VIGGO420 All the lines are in the vector `mylines`. To print all the lines do e.g. `for (auto const& l : mylines) { std::cout << l << '\n'; }`. To get the third line it's at index `2`, so use `mylines[2]`.

Comment: I'm a little lost, I haven't touched classes yet. I was thinking of changing the layout in the .txt file so it's in a single line.

I'm using this to get input for address and name
`cin.getline(list[i].addresse, 80, '.');`
I'm suspecting this is the reason I cant get my data in a single line instead of two lines

How am I to fix this? ;o

Comment: @VIGGO420 Then my first approach should work. The code you show in the comment, just sort `mylines` instead, and it will do what you want.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to do that instead.. But when writing data to file I still get this weird 2 lined format. `database << list[i].navn << "\t" << list[i].addresse << "\t" << list[i].alder << "\t" << list[i].tlf << "\t" << "\n"; `
I suspect it forces 2 lines when using cin.getline